# Reloading the page submitting the form twice using PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Recently i started to create a simple website with PHP and Bootstrap with three PHP pages Header.php,Footer.php and Home.php. In header page i have a buttion named signup .upon clicking signup button will pop up a modal (bootstrap modal) with signup form.in my home.php page i included both my header and footer php files.The problem with my code was when i click button the modal will be open and form will be filled by user .upon submitting the form the user will be registered and modal will be closed.but the problem is when i refresh the home page the user is again registering .so what i need is reloading the page after submitting the modal form should not again submit the user.can someone suggest me doing it ..

This is my modal in header.php

```
       <div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="Home.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label> <input
                            type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                            placeholder="Enter email"  name="userEmail" required=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">Username</label> <input
                            type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername1"
                            placeholder="Enter username"  name="name" required=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label> <input
                            type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                            placeholder="Password"  name="password" required=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Confirm Password</label> <input
                            type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2"
                            placeholder="Re-enter Password" 
                            name="confirm_password" required=""/>
                    </div>

                    <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
                    </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"
                        name="gender" value="Female">Female
                    </label> 
                    <div class="checkbox ">
                        <label id="lgcheck"> <input type="checkbox" name= "terms"/> Check me out
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn bsubmit btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>

                </form>


            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save"">Save
                    changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close"
                    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Home.php file

```
     <?php include_once 'Header.php';?>
      <?php include_once 'db/Conection.php';?>
       <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<?php
$register = array ();
/* Form Required Field Validation */
if (isset ( $_POST ['submit'] )) {
    if (isset ( $_POST ['userEmail'] )) {
        $userEmail = $_POST ['userEmail'];
    } 
    if (isset ( $_POST ['name'] )) {
        $name = $_POST ['name'];
    }
    if (isset ( $_POST ['password'] )) {
        $password = $_POST ['password'];
    } 
    if (isset ( $_POST ['confirm_password'] )) {
        $confirm_password = $_POST ['confirm_password'];
    } 
    $my_query = "select * from users where username like '$userEmail' ";
    $res = mysqli_query ( $conn, $my_query );

    if (mysqli_num_rows ( $res ) > 0) {
        echo "user exists";
    } else {
        $my_query = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,password,phonenumber) values ('$userEmail','$name','$password','$confirm_password') ";
        if ($conn->query ( $my_query ) === TRUE) {
            echo "registered successfully";
        } else {

            echo "failed" . "</br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }

}else{
    echo "hiii";
}
?></div>
```

I want to redirect to my same homepage without resubmittimg the form.

Comment: After submitting - redirect user.

Comment: Like @u_mulder said, redirect user to the same page. You can do this with header('Location:/'); function. Beware not to output any data before header() function is called

Comment: add the header('Location:/'); after echo "registered successfully"; if you want to show the success message just create session and display the success message

Comment: @dass your code will fail. Quote from php manual "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP."

Comment: yeah i know the echo wont be displayed.

Comment: ia hve tried by adding header('Location:/') .but it failed

Comment: it should be header('Location:home.php');

Comment: yeah dass .i have tried as  header('Location:home.php');but it is not working

Comment: still the modal displaying after register/??

Comment: actually modal is not dispalying again on refreshing only the page dispatying with echo message user exists

Comment: what you should do is post the form to other page, for example register.php to register the user and redirect back to home.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122477/discussion-between-dass-and-user3860618).